# How can I get the ListString or List Number of Word list using Apache POI?

Tags: excel, kotlin, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I'm trying to manipulate a Word docx file and produce an Excel spreadsheet using Apache POI. One requirement deals with numbered lists. Given Word text:

```
1.0 PURPOSE
1.1 SCOPE
2.0 PLACE
3.0 PERFORMANCE
```

I need to produce the following Excel rows:

| Element | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | PURPOSE |
| 1.1 | SCOPE |
| 2.0 | PLACE |
| 3.0 | PERFORMANCE |

I don't control the Word document I'm accepting as input, so I can't guarantee the author has been consistent in their use of numbered lists vs. typed and formatted text. In the above example items 1.0 and 1.1 were simply typed in with a tab between number and text. While items 2.0 and 3.0 were numbered list items. So I can't just start counting at the first list item and be sure of getting the right values.

I can get the document and paragraphs using the following Kotlin code:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFNumbering
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream

    val file = File("path/to/file.docx")
    FileInputStream(file.absolutePath).use { fis ->
        val document = XWPFDocument(fis)
        document.paragraphs
            .stream()
            .filter { !it.text.isNullOrBlank() }
            .forEach { p -> 
                // extract row data
            }
    }
    // Build Excel sheet
```

I can build the Excel sheet easily once I get the data.

I can get the list text (such as "PERFORMANCE") from `p.text`. But I need to retrieve the value "3.0" to insert it into the correct Excel cell. I can get all the paragraph properties, such as `p.numFmt`, `p.Ilvl`, `p.numId` and `p.numLevelText` and the document's `XWPFNumbering` object. It seems like there should be a way to extract the list number for a given paragraph using that information, but I haven't found any documentation that explains it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71497815/how-is-the-best-way-to-extract-a-section-from-word-document-with-apache-poi/71508345#71508345. I doubt there is a less complex solution.